# Bitmap image compare

Tags: android-image, android

Is there a way to look for the implementation/source code of this method? It's in API need this to compare two images because it keeps overwriting the original image and after several times of converting the imageview to a bitmap, the image doesn't look very nice anymore.
`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)`

I am doing this method to create a bitmap from the image and setting it again as an imageview to let the user edit his picture.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(ImageView imageView) {

    BitmapDrawable mDrawable =  (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

    Bitmap b = mDrawable.getBitmap();
    return b;
}
```

However, after several times of saving and retrieving it from the database to edit it, the image turns from this: [image]

to this:
[image]

and then finally this:
[image]

So i need a way of detecting whether the image hasn't been changed for me not to resave the byte array of this bitmap to the database.

Comment: could you please elaborate since I didn't get you?

Comment: basically i need a way to compare two bitmap images, whether pixel by pixel or by whole bitmaps.

Comment: @louieansonng have you got any kind of solution?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (based on additional info)

You are probably saving the image as a JPEG, which is a lossy format.  Every time you save you will lose quality.  If you are loading and saving the image multiple times, either use PNG or keep another copy with the text of the image with the text -- when you need to update it, start with the original again.

OLD ANSWER:

It probably has nothing to do with sameAs, and somewhere else you are doing something to change the image.

The source is here https://android.googlesource.com.

`sameAs` is a JNI function implemented in C, you can find it here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp

Comment: I was thinking of using sameAs to check if both images are the same instead of implementing my own